# Check clientside if current user has contribute permissions on current site?

Tags: display-template

I would like to check in the item displaytemplate if the current user has contribute permissions on the current item. The current item is an site object because in my search query I use `contentclass:"STS_Site"`. How to do that?

My target is to show the results where the current user has contribute permissions, in an other way. like a red border or something. Is this also possible with promoted results?

Comment: How do you want to check? using javascript?

Comment: What action you want to perform if a user has contribute permissions on an item?

Comment: I would like to show the item in an other way. Add some extra css styling like a red border or something.

Answer (score 0):

Check it using javascript. Make a `GET` request to the following `URL`

```
/_api/web/CurrentUser?$expand=groups
```

Above `URL` will return you current user's details along with user groups. From user's groups, you can check easily user has contribute permission or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code in your Item Display template.I would highly recommend to think of an alternative , because every item will make a call to SharePoint, so it would take few more seconds to check the permission.

```
   function CheckPermission(url) {
        var isContributor = false;
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);
        var currentSite = clientContext.get_web();
        clientContext.load(currentSite);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            var basePerm = new SP.BasePermissions();
            basePerm.set(SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems);
            basePerm.set(SP.PermissionKind.addListItems);
            basePerm.set(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems);
            basePerm.set(SP.PermissionKind.deleteListItems);
            isContributor = web.doesUserHavePermissions(basePerm);
            if(isContributor)
            {
                //user has contribute permission
            }
            else{
                //user does not have contribute permission
            }
        }, function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args);
        });
    }
```

Comment: If got an exception "Object doesn't support this action" on this row: var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(url);. Do you now why? I add this javascript inside the item displaytemplate

Comment: Make sure you pass the correct url to the method. Also SP.js is loaded before the call to this method